# "API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API."

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, geocoding

I've been trying to access geocoding and geolocating, it keeps giving me different errors every time.
The error I am currently on is:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error
> at _.se.captureStackTrace

When I print the response of my promise it print an array with the following error messge:

> API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API.

Additionally I get this error too when trying to use geometry:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'geometry')

Here is my code in my header:

```
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyAPIKey&callback=initMap&v=beta&libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@1.1.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

then additional code after my body:

```
    function initMap(id, addy, city, state){
      var x = document.getElementById(id);
      
      if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      }
      else{ 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      }

      var location = addy + " " + city + "  " + state;
        axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',{
            params:{
            address: location,
            key: 'MyAPIKey',
            libraries: "geometry"
          }
      })
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
        latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng(a,b);
        x.innerHTML = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latLngA, latLngB)/1000).toFixed(2) + "km";
      })
    }
    
    window.initMap = initMap;
```

Answer (score -1):

To use this Google Maps API key open your [GCP containing this key](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials),
remove referer restrictions from this key properties
[Key restrictions - Set an application restriction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46vSP.png)
and save changes.